# Как расширить int в си

Tags: c

Здравствуйте у меня есть вот такой код на си:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main() {
  int stepen,num;
  unsigned long long int summa;

  printf("write num\n> ");
  scanf("%d", &num);

  printf("Write stepen\n> ");
  scanf("%d", &stepen);

  summa = num;
  stepen--;
  /*printf("%d %d\n",num,stepen );*/

  while (stepen != 0) {
    summa *= num;
    stepen--;
  }
  printf("%lu\n",summa);
}
```

c мелкими числами он работает идеально, но большие обрезает. Или почему то результат становится отрицательным

```
write num
5
Write stepen
55
-146682003
```

как можно это исправить?

Comment: `long long` вместо `int` Вам в помощь. Если без отрицательных работаете, то `unsigned long long`.

Comment: Как вообще `printf("%lu\n", summa);` может вывести отрицательное число? Не верю!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

вы поставили тип `long long`, а в `scanf` используете `%d`

требуется использовать `%lld`

```
long long c;
scanf("%lld", &c);
printf("%lld", c);
```

если же вы хотите сделать целый тип неограниченной длины, то считывать вы его минимум должны как строку и выводить как строку, а работать с этим типом (сложения, вычитания, деления, умножения) придется как с массивом `int` самому реализовывая увеличение массива и обработку переноса разрядов

Comment: Где вы нашли у автора вопроса тип `long long`?

Comment: @ wololo - `unsigned long long int summa;`

Comment: Но считывает то он в `stepen` и `num`, имеющие тип `int`. И `unsigned long long` это не `long long`.

Answer (score 0):

Можете попробывать этот код

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
 
int main()
{
    int a, b;
    cin >> a >> b; // a - число которая возводится в степень, b - степень числа a
 
    const int maxsize = 500000;
    int mas[maxsize];
    mas[1] = 1;
 
    int c = 0, len = 1;
    for(int i = 1; i <= b; ++i)
    {
        for(int j = 1; j <= len; ++j)
        {
            mas[j] = mas[j] * a + c;
            c = mas[j] / 10;
            mas[j] = mas[j] % 10;
        } 
        while(c > 0)
        {
            len++;
            mas[len] = c % 10;
            c /= 10;
        }
    }
 
    while(mas[len] == 0 && len > 1) len--;
 
    for(int i = len; i >= 1; i--) cout << mas[i];
 
    return 0;
}
```